# convert GIcon to QIcon

Tags: qt, type-conversion, glib

Is there a way to convert between these datatypes? I'm working with Qt but still need some of glib capabilities and I haven't found a way to do this. I need to get a list of the installed applications with GAppInfo and show it in a QListView and to do so I need to get the icon for those applications. Extracting it using g_app_info_get_icon returns a GIcon and what I need to work with is a QIcon in order to get it's QVariant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> GIcon does not provide the actual pixmap for the icon.

You need to load an actual pixmap by requesting icon of certain size.

```
#include <gio/gdesktopappinfo.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QIcon icon;

    GAppInfo *appInfo = (GAppInfo *)g_desktop_app_info_new("vlc.desktop");
    GIcon *gicon = g_app_info_get_icon(appInfo);
    QList<int> sizes; sizes << 16 << 24 << 32 << 48 << 64;
    foreach (int size, sizes) {
        GtkIconInfo *iconInfo = gtk_icon_theme_lookup_by_gicon(gtk_icon_theme_get_default(), gicon, size, (GtkIconLookupFlags)0);
        GdkPixbuf *pixbuf = gtk_icon_info_load_icon(iconInfo, NULL);
        if (pixbuf == NULL)
            continue;

        QImage image(
            gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels(pixbuf),
            gdk_pixbuf_get_width(pixbuf),
            gdk_pixbuf_get_height(pixbuf),
            gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride(pixbuf),
            QImage::Format_ARGB32);

        g_object_unref(pixbuf);

        image.save("icon-" + QString::number(size) + ".png");
        icon.addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
    }
    g_object_unref(gicon);

    return 0;
}
```